# How can I allow users to change network device settings (up/down, mode) without sudo?

Tags: networking, permissions

I'm writing an application that uses network device (CANbus).
In Linux, CAN is visible like any other net device (eg eth0).
My application needs to be able to set up network devices, put them into UP/Down states, etc.

Unfortunately when my application tried to to this (by API) I got :
`RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted`

When I run my application as root, it works as expected. But for sure I do not want to run it as root. As network devices don't have representation in `/dev/` (since a few years ago) I don't know even where to start from.

From what I checked, netdev is group of users which have rights to do such operations, but it wasn't working for me.

In other words, accessing gain can be made two ways:

- by gaining higher privileges by process (`sudo` for example)
- by lowering mandatory privileges of item (file for example)

What I expect is the way to lower mandatory privileges of particular network devices.

Comment: Try asking on [Unix and Linux stack exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) If you are not using Ubuntu this question is off topic.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu. This application will be running on embedded however now I run it on my desktop PC running Ubuntu.